# How to create context manager with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been trying to work out a a context manger for threading where I use a context manager to start a threading and close it once it is done. I have basically done

```
import threading


def test():
    print("Is the script running in test()? - ", running_thread.is_alive())


class Threads(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='Thread-test')
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stop()
        print('Force set Thread Sleeper stop_event')


print("START SCRIPT")

with Threads() as running_thread:
    test()
    print("IS alive inside context? - ", running_thread.is_alive())

print("Outside context - ", running_thread.is_alive())

print('Main Thread ends')
print("Is the script alive? - ", running_thread.is_alive())
```

**Output**

```
START SCRIPT
Is the script running in test()? -  False
IS alive inside context? -  False
Force set Thread Sleeper stop_event
Outside context -  False
Main Thread ends
Is the script alive? -  False
```

however the problem seems like no threading is running and I can't really see why it doesn't start up and closes when using context manager.

How can I easily do it and safety as well.

EDIT: A good reviewer have recommended me this, not sure if im going the correct way with it:

*You're creating and starting a thread, and throwing away its reference; so you'll never have an opportunity to join. A more careful approach would have an upper limit to the number of live threads as imposed on a thread pool; and would run test() in a context manager where the **exit** would join on all remaining threads.
If you don't have an upper limit on the thread pool and you get more product data t*han expected, you've basically made a fork bomb.

Comment: You started the thread, but nothing prevents it from *finishing* before you check. Plus, nothing cares about the event you're setting.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica hmm right.. I thought the __start__ and __exit__ would do the finish part?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't asked your thread to do anything, so it dies too quickly for you to see it as alive. You need to make it do something by passing a `target` to `Thread.__init__`, or providing a `run()` method.

Modifying your example with a `run()` method that sleeps in a loop:

```py
import threading
import time


def test():
    print("Is the script running in test()? - ", running_thread.is_alive())


class Threads(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='Thread-test')
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.join()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stop()
        print('Force set Thread Sleeper stop_event')

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.1)


print("START SCRIPT")

with Threads() as running_thread:
    test()
    print("IS alive inside context? - ", running_thread.is_alive())

print("Outside context - ", running_thread.is_alive())

print('Main Thread ends')
print("Is the script alive? - ", running_thread.is_alive())
```

I get

```
START SCRIPT
Is the script running in test()? -  True
IS alive inside context? -  True
Force set Thread Sleeper stop_event
Outside context -  False
Main Thread ends
Is the script alive? -  False
```

Note that for the stop to work the thread has to actually check the `stop_event`.  You also need to call `join()` in your `stop()` method. This makes the thread that calls `stop()` (the main thread) wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: Oh that make sense, meaning that inside the stop() I should call self.stop() and then self.join()? I would appreciate if you could explain more regarding that part!

Comment: I think you should make the `run()` method an infinite loop (that calls `sleep()` each iteration to simulate doing something) whcih terminates only when the `stop_event` is set.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show a working `stop()` method.

Comment: The `Event` would have worked fine and provided better compatibility with other Python implementations, as well as being forward-compatible if they ever manage to remove the GIL from CPython.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Right, but would it make any difference using it now in my case as Nadva provided?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie: Technically no, but using a boolean instead of an Event here is relying on implementation details and adding risk and limitations with no benefit.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Could you please provide an example as I want to see it and get more knowledge to understand why its better on relying it? :)

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie: An example of what? Using `Event`? Basically your initial code, but have your thread's `run` do `self.stop_event.wait()`, or if you want the thread to do some actual work, have it periodically check `self.stop_event.is_set()` while it's working and terminate if the event is set.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Well the plan is that the thread will work and once its done it should terminate. That was the plan :)

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie: Well, if you just want it to terminate once its work is done, then you don't need any of this `Event`/`stop` stuff. Instead, you need to fix the code that assumes the thread isn't done.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How do I do that? I dont know how to fix the code that assumes the thread isnt done :(

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie: In the code you posted, it's not really any part of the *code* that assumes the thread isn't done. The code just prints the thread's live/dead status, and *you* assumed it would print `True`, so the "fix" is just for you to not assume that. If you had actually had some code relying on `running_thread.is_alive()` returning `True`, you would have to change the code to not rely on that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Got it. I thought that wasthe way to see if the thread was live or dead and yes, I assumed if it prints `True` then yes, but if I understand it correctly. How would I then be able to know if its actually "terminated" the thread or not

Comment: You're right, I've changed it back to an `Event`. This seems like a missing feature in Python (atomic boolean), as the whole `Event` is not really needed if we're not waiting for it.